# Adding dynamic style to material ui Menu with makeStyles not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to dynamically generate classes on the material ui Menu this way :

```
const useStyles = (props) => {
  return makeStyles({
    paper: props.style,
  });
};

const StyledMenu = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props)();
  return <Menu {...props} className={classes.paper} />;
};

render() {
const { state, fnsMenuBtn, fieldsMenuBtn, props } = this;
const { fnsMenuIsOpen, fieldsMenuIsOpen } = state;
return (
<StyledMenu
          id="fnsMenuEl"
          anchorEl={fnsMenuBtn}
          keepMounted
          open={fnsMenuIsOpen}
          style={{ border: "1px solid blue" }}
          onClose={(e) => {
            vm.setState((state, props) => {
              return {
                fnsMenuIsOpen: !state.fnsMenuIsOpen,
              };
            });
          }}
        >
          {Object.keys(formulajs).map((fnName) => (
            <MenuItem onClick={(e) => {}} key={fnName}>
              {fnName}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
 </StyledMenu>
)
}
```

But the wanted style is never added to the menu
What's wrong ?
How to do it otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted using `className` try to use `classes`

```
const StyledMenu = (props) => {
 const classes = useStyles(props)();
 return <Menu {...props} classes={{paper: classes.paper}} />;
};
```